# Start windows service as non admin

Tags: windows, service

I am trying to start a windows service through a cmd window using `sc start servicename` and `net start servicename`. However in both cases I get an error that "Access is denied". However if I go to the services app and manually right-click it and start the service it starts just fine. What am I missing here? Is it not the same user that does these two actions? And most important, how can I get this service to start through a script?